# Python PostgresQL - export to CSV not exporting all lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, csv, export-to-csv

I have a Postgresql SQL query that I want to run with Python and export this to a CSV file.

I'm quite new to Python but I've managed to write a script that can run the query and export to a file.

```
import psycopg2

# File path and name.
fileName = 'test.csv'


# Database connection variable.
connect = None

# Check if the file path exists.
if os.path.exists(filePath):

    try:

        # Connect to database.
        connect = psycopg2.connect(host="xxxx", port="5439", database="xxxx", user="xxxx", password="xxxx")

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:

        # Confirm unsuccessful connection and stop program execution.
        print("Database connection unsuccessful.")
        quit()

    # Cursor to execute query.
    cursor = connect.cursor()

    # SQL to select data from the person table.
    sqlSelect = """
SELECT * FROM TABLE
                """

    try:

        # Execute query.
        cursor.execute(sqlSelect)

        # Fetch the data returned.
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        # Extract the table headers.
        headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]

        #Print the results
        #print(pd.read_sql(sqlSelect, connect))
        print(tb.tabulate(results, headers=headers, tablefmt='psql', showindex="always", floatfmt=".10f"))

        # Open CSV file for writing.
        csvFile = csv.writer(open(filePath + fileName, 'w', newline=''),
                             delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n',
                             quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, escapechar='\\')

        # Add the headers and data to the CSV file.
        csvFile.writerow(headers)

        for row in results:
            csvFile.writerow(row)

        # Message stating export successful.
        print("Data export successful.")

        # csvFile.close()

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:

        # Message stating export unsuccessful.
        print("Data export unsuccessful.")
        quit()

    finally:

        # Close database connection.
        cursor.close()
        connect.close()

else:

    # Message stating file path does not exist.
    print("File path does not exist.")


cursor.close()
connect.close()
```

The query I run generates 70 lines of results (when I run it through a database program). However when I export the data to CSV it only exports 48 rows.

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Possibly because you aren't closing the csvFile?  In any case, I'd recommend using the built-in copy_to in psycopg2's cursor class.  It will create the csv file for you.

Comment: Thanks! good spot. I used the `with` statement instead which closes the file after exporting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me with 490 rows in postgres.

Maybe your problem is in the database with some record that has some special character that causes the code to stop and not get the expected result.

Debug your script, add a print of the exception to check if that is the problem.

Comment: I printed the results and it had all 70 rows but it was the export that wasn't working properly. Jeremy had the solution. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question though.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you could solve your problem with Jeremy's solution